# How to show a set is path-connected?

Tags: general-topology

Say $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\tau=\{\emptyset,X,\{a\},\{c\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,b,d\}, \{b,c,d\}, 
\{b,d\}\}$

This is a topological space as it satisfies the appropriate properties but how do you show $\tau$ is (or is not) path-connected?

Comment: If $\{a\}$ and $\{c\}$ are open, then $\{a,c\}$ must be open too.

Comment: I think $\tau$ is the topology on $X$, and I suppose you want to show that $X$ is path connected? You basically need to find for each pair of elements in $X$ a continuous path from one to the other one. In some cases you can try to create one closed loop that starts and ends in the same element and covers all of the others.

Comment: what is path conenctedness for you??

Comment: Based on your definition, it's not a topological space.

Comment: If $\{a\}$ and $\{c\}$ are open subsets, $\{a,c\}$ should be open too.

Comment: This updated space is still not connected since it is the disjoint union of the open sets $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b,d\}$.

Comment: but that doesn't mean its not path connected

Comment: Not connected implies not path connected in general. The two properties are equivalent for finite spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\{a\}$ and $\{b,c,d\}$ are open, disjoint and complementary sets, the topological space is not even connected.

Comment: so it's not even a topological space

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with your topology and this example certainly isn't path-connected even if you use the topology generated by $\tau$, but here is the idea of how to define paths in finite spaces and show that a [finite space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space) is path-connected (which presumably is what you are looking to do).

For every pair of points $x,y\in X$, you need to make sure there is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to X$ with $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. This becomes easier if you use the fact that being in the same path-component is an equivalence relation.

For example, let $X=\{a,b\}$ with the topology $\tau=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. This space is path-connected since you can define $f:[0,1]\to X$ by $f(t)=a$ for $0\leq t<1$ and $f(1)=b$. This is continuous since the preimage of every open set in $X$ is an open interval in $[0,1]$. In particular, $f^{-1}(\{a\})=[0,1)$.

Similarly, if $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with topology $\tau=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,c,d\}\}$, then $X$ is path-connected, because we can define a path from $a$ to every other point: if $x\in X$ is any point, define $g([0,1))=a$ and $g(1)=x$ to get a continuous path from $a$ to $x$. All points lie in the same path-component so $X$ must be path-connected.

You can use these types of constructions to convince yourself that **any finite connected space is also path-connected**.